# Best way to dual boot in this scenario?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, dual-boot, memory

I need to dual boot Ubuntu for work and Windows 11 for entertainment (gaming mostly) and I've got a 240 GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD. I was planning on leaving the SSD for Ubuntu and the HDD for Windows 11, since when I tried to have both OSes on the SSD, I had an extreme shortage of storage space, but some say that it would be best to have both OSes on a partitioned HDD.

I believe having each OS on a separate drive would make it safer during updates and the like, avoiding the off chance of windows 11 bugging/deleting grub or causing other such problems, and I don't need more than 150 GB or so. What do you recommend in my case? Thanks a lot for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

- buy a second SSD from amazon, or wherever, for $20
- have only one SSD physically installed in pc (or server)
- install Windows 11 on it
- remove Windows 11 SSD, install new $20 SSD in pc so only one disk is now installed
- install Linux on that SSD
- install the `ntfs-3g` linux rpm so linux can access NTFS file systems
- in pc/server BIOS (EFI) arrange for *dual boot* to happen at that level

  - my asrock mobo for example has a boot selection screen that times out after 3 second, default boot is windows for me
  - a dell pc hit F12 to enter boot selection text menu, and so on
  - peruse your motherboard bios capabilities first to understand what you can set up
- boot windows 11 and having the 1 TB HDD connected, format the 1tb hdd as NTFS
- when you boot linux, you can have the 1 TB HDD mounted as /data
- you can also ntfs mount your windows 11 ssd, but be mindful of causing disk checks

  - the fix there in win10 was turning off hibernation or making shutdown really a shutdown (i forget what that was called).  I don't know how they are doing that in win11.
  - was `disable fast startup` in win10

Comment: There's a couple complications there mostly due to where I'm at and my wonky windows 10 installation: an SSD costs more than 10 times as much where I live and I can't afford one at all atm, and I have to upgrade my windows 10 to 11 but first I have to reformat the HDD from MBR to GPT and reinstall it. What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: keep win11 on the ssd, put linux on the HDD.  on the HDD make a ntfs `/data` partition of desired size so that win11 can mount it.  you will take a performance hit using a hdd for [any] operating system versus using an ssd, but I think this would be the best way to go given what you have to work with.  With win11 being used for entertainment & gaming have that on the ssd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation, and my solution was to install both OSes in the SSD, and simply mount them as I needed, in my case:

- Linux demands way less storage space, so I went with installing it on the SSD normally and simply mounting my `/home` partition on the HDD. For me works flawlessly.
- Windows had the rest of the storage in both drives, without any headaches.

About the change of Windows deleting the GRUB partition, it can happen and has happened to me, but it's not very hard to fix and a live boot with the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#:%7E:text=Boot%2DRepair%20is%20a%20simple,some%20upgrade%20breaks%20GRUB%2C%20etc.) utility should repair it quite easily.

But YMMV, and if you *really* want to be safe, separate drives are the way to go. Just bear in mind your HDD will be **significantly** slower in just about any task with either OS.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll mull over it for a while and then make the plunge, but I think I can deal with the trade-off of more safety in exchange for a slow windows for a while, at least until I can get a new SSD.